# "yield return" from event handler

Tags: c#, lambda, ienumerable

I have a class which takes a stream in the constructor. You can then set up callbacks for various events, and then call `StartProcessing`. The issue is that I want to use it from a function which should return an `IEnumerable`.

Example:

```
public class Parser
{
    public Parser(System.IO.Stream s) { // saves stream and does some set up }
    public delegate void OnParsedHandler(List<string> token);
    public event OnParsedHandler OnParsedData;
    public void StartProcessing()
    {
        // reads stream and makes callback when it has a whole record
    }
 }

 public class Application
 {
      public IEnumerable<Thing> GetThings(System.IO.Stream s)
      {
            Parser p = new Parser(s);
            p.OnParsedData += (List<string> str) => 
            {
                Thing t = new Thing(str[0]);
                // here is where I would like to yield
                // but I can't
                yield return t;
            };


            p.StartProcessing();
      }
 }
```

Right now my solution, which isn't so great, is to put them all the Things into a List which is captured by the lambda, and then iterate over them after calling StartProcessing.

```
public class Application
 {
      public IEnumerable<Thing> GetThings(System.IO.Stream s)
      {
            Parser p = new Parser(s);
            List<Thing> thingList = new List<Thing>();

            p.OnParsedData += (List<string> str) => 
            {
                Thing t = new Thing(str[0]);
                thingList .Add(t);
            };


            p.StartProcessing();
            foreach(Thing t in thingList )
            {
                  yield return t;
            }
      }
 }
```

The issue here is that now I have to save all of the `Thing` objects into list.

Comment: So `StartProcessing` synchronously parses the entire stream, periodically throwing out parsed items via the event handler?

Comment: Or, does `StartProcessing` work asynchronously internally?  It seems a bit odd of an API to design around.

Comment: StartProcessing is synchronous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have here is that you don't fundamentally have a "pull" mechanic here, you're trying to push data from the parser.  If the parser is going to push data to you, rather than letting the caller pull the data, then `GetThings` should return an `IObservable`, rather than an `IEnumerable`, so the caller can consume the data when it's ready.

If it really is important to have a pull mechanic here then `Parser` shouldn't fire an event to indicate that it has new data, but rather the caller should be able to ask it for new data and have it get it; it should either return all of the parsed data, or itself return an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I see what you are saying. The issue is that the Parser can raise multiple types of events, having a pull method might not work. I'll have to take another look at possibly rearranging the code.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. I would like to build upon what ***@servy*** has said regarding [push and pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792966/data-pull-vs-push-oop-approach#answer-10095995). In your implementation above, you are effectively adapting a push mechanism to a pull interface.

Now, first things first. You have not specified whether the call to the `StartProcessing()` method is a blocking call or not. A couple of remarks regarding that:

- If the method is blocking (synchronous), then there is really no point in adapting it to a pull model anyway. The caller will see all the data processed in a single *blocking* call.
- In that regard, receiving the data indirectly via an event handler scatters into two seemingly unrelated constructs what should otherwise be a single, cohesive, explicit operation. For example:

  ```
  void ProcessAll(Action<Thing> callback);
  ```

On the other hand, if the `StartProcessing()` method actually spawns a new thread (maybe better named `BeginProcessing()` and follow the [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx) or another async processing pattern), you could adapt it to a pull machanism by means of a synchronization construct using a wait handle: [`ManualResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx), mutex and the like. Pseudo-code:

```
public IEnumerable<Thing> GetThings(System.IO.Stream s)
{
    var parser = new Parser(s);
    var waitable = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    Thing item = null;

    parser.OnParsedData += (Thing thing) => 
    {
        item = thing;
        waitable.Set();
    };

    IAsyncResult result = parser.BeginProcessing();
    while (!result.IsCompleted)
    {
        waitable.WaitOne();
        yield return item;            
    }
}
```

## Disclaimer

*The above code serves only as a means for presenting an idea. It is not thread-safe and the synchronization mechanics do not work properly. See the [producer-consumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) pattern for more information.*