# Object orientation fundamental - linking results of object to another

Tags: c++, oop

This seems like a fundamental that I've completely forgotten from comp sci 20 years ago.

How would I link/trigger an object function from another object. Or what is the name of the concept I'm trying to find? (c++ if it matters)

My example is I have a sensor which has accumulators. The accumulators have an array of time interval readings. They accumulate values until their interval is complete and add that to the readings array.

I wanted to make the accumulators flexible, different intervals, timeframes, or the amount of accumulators for each sensor. Eg. 1 hour with 1 min intervals, 1 day with hourly...

I have a class for the Sensor, and Accumulator. But how do I declare multiple accumulators and allow smaller timeframe readings to bubble up to the next higher readings?

==========================

To add a more concrete example because I'm struggling to explain clearly...

Example function in sensor class:
Sensor.addAccumulator(timeframe, interval)

So first timeframe could be a 1 hour timeframe and 1 min interval.
Then another accumulator added with a 24 hour timeframe and 30 min interval.
Next 1 week with 12 hour interval.

The sensor would has a function to get the current reading then gives it to accumulator to process.

But when 1 min of data was accumulated, how can I give that to the next higher timeframe?

I could just give the readings to every accumulator but the calculations become redundant and it's on a microcontroller.

=========

If I had a high powered device I'd dump the values in a time series database with data retention policies that downsample older data.

Comment: so the "Accumulators" are declared as member elements of the "Sensor"?

Comment: and then the "Accumulator" has its own definition as a class?

Comment: Maybe we can tag this as "C++" if you want to post a snippet.

Comment: Yes, I created a sensor class which has a function to get a realtime reading from the sensor and gives it to the accumulator class to do the calculations on.

Comment: I only have one accumulator right now because I don't know how to link a higher level one. Basically the higher level ones are downsampling the data but I'm trying to avoid redundant recalculations of realtime data for every time frame.

Comment: You could be looking for "Callback". If not, I'm not sure what you are asking

Comment: I'm just gonna throw in an answer.

Comment: I'm having trouble describing what I'm asking. I'll add a more specific example.

Comment: I'mma post it anyway and you decide later.

Comment: Hey cool, I didn't know you were tinkering around with hardware too.  I never got into any of that.

Comment: One difficulty here is that, as you say, you want to make the accumulators flexible — but that means you can't necessarily implement them as a hierarchy. Imagine you add two accumulators, one with a 2-minute interval, another with a 5-minute interval. The second accumulator can't draw its data from the first, the resolution is wrong. So if you're going to permit that, you may have to treat each accumulator as wholly separate and sacrifice the efficiency of chaining them.

Answer (score 1):

What you needed to do was to have a linked list for the accumulators.

So then you'd have your `class Sensor` but as a member you'd have an element

`mll_Accumulator *accumulator;`

And what that is is the first element of the linked list.  To make a linked list, recall, you have to have a type declaration that had an element that was a pointer to an instance of an object of the same type.

And then if you have `mll_Accumulator *next;`, then to access that through a linked list that starts with `mll_Accumulator seed = new mll_Accumulator;`, you would access it by dereferencing the member element with `seed->next` or iterate through with `seed->next->next`, and you would lengthen the linked list by calling, or perhaps iterating through the list to the end where `seed->next` is null and calling `seed->next = new mll_Accumulator;`, because otherwise you could be looking at arbitrary memory locations.

and I was thinking `mll_`- as a naming convention for a prefix could be read as "member linked list".  But that's probably what it was: a linked list.

Comment: Side note: remember that C++ has a `std::list` (defined such that the only straight forward way to implement it is a doubly linked list) and `std::forward_list` (almost certainly a singly linked list) built-in. It's pretty rare to need to roll-your-own linked list. That said, a `std::deque` might be a better datatype for the job described by this answer.

Comment: @user4581301 There's always space for another answer.

Comment: I'm not sure enough about what the question is to write an answer. I just wanted to point out that what you're suggesting isn't as hard to implement as it sounds. The tools are already there.

Answer (score 0):

I expressed my concerns about the flexibility of the `Accumulator` design in a comment, but setting that aside — if you *do* want to implement hierarchical `Accumulator`s, I think in terms of OOP the best option would be to flip your classes around — don't have a `Sensor` that holds `Acccumulator`s, but rather have `Accumulator`s that hold an abstract `DataSource` — that `DataSource` could *either* be the `Sensor` itself, or another `Accumulator`.

The `DataSource` interface provides a `.getValues(size_t count)` function, which for the `Sensor` would only support `.getValues(1)` to read the hardware and returns the measurement, and for an `Accumulator` reads that many stored values and returns them. (So you'd need a `std::vector<ValueType>` as the return type, even for the `Sensor`. Or maybe you want to have the `DataSource` sum the list of values and return the result. That lets you keep the return type as a single `ValueType` value, instead of a `std::vector`.)

When taking another `Accumulator` as a `DataSource`, the "parent" `Accumulator` would compute a `frequency` for itself as a multiple of the child `Accumulator`'s own `interval`, and reads that many values from the `DataSource` every `interval`. So if a 10-minute-interval `Accumulator` is pulling from a 1-minute-interval `Accumulator`, its `frequency` is 10 and when it's triggered, it calls `DataSource.getValues(10)` on its `DataSource`. Pulling from a 2-minute-interval `Accumulator`, it would call `.getValues(5)` once every 10 minutes.

If you keep a master `std::vector` of `Accumulator`s and sort it so the shortest-interval ones always update first, then they'll have data ready for their parents whenever they're polled.

This breaks the contention by some that [push is better than pull](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5855531/200794), but it better expresses the relationship between the `Accumulator`s in the hierarchy. Each `Accumulator` can only have one `DataSource` and only has to deal with retrieving data from that source. A given `Accumulator` may be polled by *multiple* parents (think 2-, 3-, and 7-minute-interval `Accumulator`s, all reading from the same 1-minute-interval `DataSource`), and the child `Accumulator` doesn't have to know or care about that complexity.