# How to filter data in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My understanding is I can filter data using stream and put it to specific topics.

**Problem :**
The producer sends data with field country. Then stream processing filters these data and puts to topics by country code.

As result those consumers who are subscribed to specific countries(code) would get message.

Problem is it requires a lot of topics by count of countries. And in the feature I need to do the same with countries.

How to organize it in Kafka and filter data?

Comment: Why would you need multiple topics? Can you give an example?

Comment: One topic contains orders for USA country, another for UK, and etc.

Comment: Sure, but why do those need to be topics instead of keys of records in partitions in one `country`topic?

Comment: Because on another side there are a consumers (web, mobile apps) which subscribe to specific countries from where they want to receive the orders.

Comment: You can have separate consumer groups and assign consumer instances to singular (or groups of) partitions that only store specific country codes

Comment: Either way, countries have changed over the course of history, and it's unclear to me how you account on adding new topics or partitions or remapping old data if/when this happens

Comment: Yes, there is a case when order appears with another country name.

Comment: Sure, but let's say Scotland declares independence from the UK and you've got previous data that's written with UK country code that should be removed and written to some new SCO country code... Just something to think about

Comment: Yes, you are right :)

Comment: Do you have any examples similar with my?

Comment: The below answer is "correct". Not sure what else you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few options here :

**Kafka Streaming** : With kafka streaming you can filter data as per your need and write it to the new topics. Consumers can consume messages from those new topics.

**Filter Data on the Consumer Side** : You consume the data and filter the data as per required criteria on the consumer side.

**Use Separate partitions for separate country code** : You define total partitions of this topic as per the number of country codes and make country code as key. Now make your consumers direct to right partition for consuming country specific messages.

Comment: Thank you, first point you wrote I use now. So I need the third within partitions by count of countries. I wonder how then psuh data from concumer (python script) to consumers(web apps, mobile apps)?

Comment: @Aurica Use Websockets or write the Kafka data to some type of database which your web/mobile clients will query via some API

Comment: Thank you, how to make a right decision what to use, websoket or db (pull). Where can I find use cases?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792966/data-pull-vs-push-oop-approach, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706186/push-pull-mechanism-observer-pattern